# How to edit the checkout.tpl in journal onepage checkout

Tags: opencart

I have installed Journal 2 theme in an *opencart* installation.  I want to edit the `checkout.tpl` to display the product's category name. I edit the file

```
view/theme/journal2/template/checkout/checkout.tpl
```

but it seems that this is not the file because every change I make doesn't appear. I have enabled one page checkout in `journal2`.

Answer (score 1):

You are editing the wrong file. You should  edit the checkout.tpl file found on the following path:

```
/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/journal2/checkout/
```